# Mostrar resultados en un select desde la base de datos

Tags: php, mysql, html5

Quiero jalar datos de una base de datos pero que solo se muestren los campos que sean igual a 1 y su id igual a 7 digamos en un select de html.

Me explico mejor: Si su id es igual a 7 pero su campo "casa" es igual a uno, no quiero que se muestre "casa" en el select

Comment: para que la consulta devuelva ciertos campos debes especificarlo después de SELECT, si quieres filtrar solo debes poner las condiciones dentro del WHERE un ejemplo sería. `SELECT tabla.id FROM tabla WHERE tabla.id = 7 and tabla.casa = 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es muy claro lo que necesitas hacer, pero por lo que entendí espero que esto te sirva:

```
select * from table_name where id = 1 and casa != 7;
```

donde `!=` es diferente al valor dado.

Por otro lado si necesitas diferentes valores:

```
select * from table_name where id = 1 and casa not in (7, 8, 9, ..., n);
```

Comment: si no es muy claro ¿por qué respondes a la pregunta si es muy probable que no sea lo que necesita?

Comment: Hola @Adrian ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! En estos casos, donde la pregunta no es clara, conviene esperar a que el autor aclare qué está preguntando antes de responder. La idea es agregar preguntas y respuestas de calidad en el sitio. Por otro lado, si lo que se busca en ganar reputación, este tipo de respuestas, por más que pudieran llegar a obtener 15 puntos por ser aceptadas, son en preguntas que terminan siendo cerradas y eliminadas, y por lo tanto se pierden esos puntos que podrías haber obtenido

Comment: Yo opino que esta seria la respuesta correcta y no deberia estar en espera ya que si alguien pudo responder esta suficientemente completo para entenderlo, no es algo que requiera mucha explicacion